# Core Data - NSSet of NSString

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Is it possible to have `NSSet` of `NSString` objects in a core data object?

For example I have `ClassA` that is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`, I want that `ClassA` will hold a set of strings.

I know I can create some kind of ManagedString that is a subclass of `NSManagedObject` and use it, but I prefer not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the type of an attribute to "Transformable" then you can simply assign
an `NSSet` to it:

```
e.setOfStrings = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", nil];
```

Core Data will use the `NSCoding` methods to transform the set into a data blob and
store that in the SQLite store.

A disadvantage might be that you cannot search for strings in the set in a fetch request.
If you need that feature then you have to use a to-many relationship instead.